# View.draw(canvas) poor quality of child views

Tags: android, image, canvas, bitmap, draw

I am trying to solve problem when I get bitmap from view (with bad quality of childviews) and store it as PNG. There are some taken pictures using this code:

```
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                        Math.round(General.getDisplayWidthPx()), Math.round(General.getDisplayHeightPx()), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

                final Canvas canvas = new Canvas( b );

                wallFrame.invalidate();
                wallFrame.draw( canvas );

                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);

                b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);

                out.flush();
                out.close();
```

When the childview is small the quality of childview is terrible.
[image: Smaller childview - worse quality]

But when it's larger the quality is better.
[image: Larger childview - better quality]

As you can see the smaller the picture, the lower the quality. I also tried deprecated methods:

```
wallFrame.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap b = wallFrame.getDrawingCache();
```

wallFrame is [ZoomLayout](https://github.com/shopgun/zoomlayout) which extends RelativeLayout. Child views in wallFrame are [SubScalingImageView](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view) which extends View. I think it's not caused by SubScalingImageView I've tried standard ImageView and result was the same. When I take screenshot of app, the result is better.

Pictures are loaded from user storage using Uri (so not from drawable). SubscalingImageView has own decoders. In app the quality of pictures is perfect.

I think problem is somewhere in view.draw(canvas). But I have no idea how to edit it to make it work.
I appreciate every idea. Thank you!

Comment: Try `paint.setFilterBitmap()`

Comment: In SubScalingImageView there is a method called createPaints() called from onDraw(..). It initialize bitmapPaint and sets antialiasing, dither and filterBitmap to true, I also tried set it to false, but no change. The variable bitmapPaint is used in onDraw - method canvas.drawBitmap(...,bitmapPaint); Or did you thought to set it somewhere else? I can't edit class View.java. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try it with tiling disabled?

Comment: Didn't work too. :( But it was something I've not try. Thanks.